# How to convert below shell script for more number of command line input arguments.

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments

```
#!/bin/bash
a=${2}
b=${1}
let "c=b+a"
echo $c
```

Script is executed by using commad ./scriptname arg1 arg2
where arg1 and arg2 are integer type passed while running the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum over any number of arguments, consider this script:

```
$ cat ./sum
#!/bin/sh
( IFS=+; echo "$*" | bc ; )
```

As examples:

```
$ ./sum 2 4
6
$ ./sum 2 4 2 8
16
```

Notes:

1. The construct `$*` returns all the arguments to the script separated by the first character in the variable `IFS`.  By default the first character in IFS is a blank space, so, as an example:

   ```
   $ echo "$*"
   2 4 2 8
   ```

   But, we want to indicate addition, so we set `IFS=+`.  Thus:

   ```
   $ ( IFS=+; echo "$*" )
   2+4+2+8
   ```

   This latter is now in the form suitable for `bc`:

   ```
   $ ( IFS=+; echo "$*" | bc )
   16
   ```
2. Because the above uses `bc`, it can be used for floating point as well as integer addition.
3. The parens, `(...)`, were used to create a subshell.  For the simple script shown, that is not necessary.  If the actual script were more complicated, then there is likely an advantage to keeping the change in `IFS` local.

#### Alternative

Consider this script:

```
$ cat sum2
#!/bin/sh
( IFS=+; echo $(( $* )) )
```

Example:

```
$ ./sum2 1 2 4
7
```

This approach uses bash's arithmetic, `$((...))`, to do the computation which limits it to integers.

Comment: I think it would be useful to explain the meaning of `IFS` ... I guess Sachin is a beginner with shell scripts

Comment: @JimHawkins Good point: I added an explanation of `IFS` and `$*`.